# packaging Error for amd64

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit, packaging

I am trying to package lttoolbox-3.2 for ubuntu , I successfully created ppa and built 32-bit packages. but it always fails for 64 bit

failed log
:https://launchpad.net/~aboobackervyd/+archive/apertium/+build/5395410/+files/buildlog_ubuntu-raring-amd64.lttoolbox_3.2-1ubuntu8_FAILEDTOBUILD.txt.gz

ppa link : https://launchpad.net/~aboobackervyd/+archive/apertium

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was architecture:all in the debian control file, replacement of it by 'any' fixed the problem